# why visvamitra was misled by Menaka ? Did visvamitra was discourage by his spiritual practice after the misled by Menaka?

Tags: mahabharata

why visvamitra  was  misled by Menaka  ? Did visvamitra   was  discourage   by his spiritual practice   after the misled  by Menaka?